# Scala: How to enrich a class with a property

Tags: scala

I'm trying to enrich a class with a custom property:

```
class MyClass {

   def printNumber(n: Int) = {
     println(n)
   }
}

class MyClassWithName(myClass: MyClass, val name: String) {}

implicit def myClassWithName(myClass: MyClass, name: String) = new MyClassWithName(myClass, name)
```

Then I try to access custom property `name` like this...

```
val c = myClassWithName(new MyClass, "jonny")
c.printNumber(5)
```

... but it does not compile:

```
value printNumber is not a member of MyClassWithName.
```

Am I missing something? Tx.

Comment: I'm totally lost trying to understand what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you can prefix your question with a general statement of what kind of functionality you expect. My guess is, you want to be able to treat an instance of `MyClassWithName` is if it were `MyClass`?

Comment: You are not accessing property `name`, but method `printNumber`. Why do you make a method implicit that you call explicitly? `MyClassWithName` has no method `printNumber` so how do you expect that to compile?

Comment: why don't you use c.myClass.printNumber(5)? As the printNumber method is inside the MyClass class.

Comment: What Jasper says is correct. I know I could implement a wrapper... I was just wondering if there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to add a `name` property and nothing else you could do it like this:

```
object MyClassPlus {
  private val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[MyClass,String]
}

implicit class MyClassPlus(val myClass: MyClass) extends AnyVal {

  def name = MyClassPlus.map(myClass) 

  def name_= (value: String) {
    MyClassPlus.map(myClass) = value
  }
}
```

You can then access name as if it's a member of `MyClass`:

```
scala> val c = new MyClass
c: MyClass = MyClass@78e312af

scala> c.name = "foo"
c.name: String = foo

scala> c.name
res4: String = foo
```

Note that with this approach the `equals` method of `MyClass` should test for reference equality. Otherwise the `Map` has to be changed to use reference equality instead.

---

If you want to be able to add many properties to an object at runtime and you can change the definition of the class you can extend `Dynamic`.

```
import scala.language.dynamics

class MyClass extends Dynamic {

  private val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String,String]

  // the type of value doesn't necessarily have to be String
  def updateDynamic(name: String)(value: String) {
    map(name) = value
  }

  def selectDynamic(name: String) = map(name)
}
```

Then you can add and access properties like this:

```
scala> val c = new MyClass
c: MyClass = MyClass@50f85a5f

scala> c.name = "foo"
c.name: String = foo

scala> c.name
res6: String = foo
```

If you can't change the definition of the class, you could try to do some sort of implicit conversion like this:

```
object MyClassPlus {
  private val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[(MyClass,String),String]
}

implicit class MyClassPlus(val myClass: MyClass) extends AnyVal {

  def update(name: String, value: String) {
    MyClassPlus.map((myClass, name)) = value
  }

  def apply(name: String) = MyClassPlus.map((myClass, name))
}
```

Then you can add and access properties, but with a less intuitive syntax:

```
scala> val c1 = new MyClass
c1: MyClass = MyClass@635b4736

scala> val c2 = new MyClass
c2: MyClass = MyClass@1be2e9e5

scala> c1("name") = "foo"

scala> c2("name") = "bar"

scala> c1("name")
res2: String = foo

scala> c2("name")
res3: String = bar
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your exhaustive explanation! This is exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: I should add that if you implement the name property as a `Map` and you plan on creating a lot of instances of `MyClass` you could get into trouble, cause they won't be garbage collected. It would be better to use something like a [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) instead of the default `Map` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted the opposite:

```
class Wrapper(original: OriginalClass) {
  def printNumber(n: Int) = println(n)
  def printName = println(original.name) // I added this method to justify wrapping of original
}

class OriginalClass(val name: String)

implicit def toWrapper(original: OriginalClass) = new Wrapper(original)

val x = new OriginalClass("johny")
// x: OriginalClass = OriginalClass@21788153

x.printName
// johny

x.printNumber(1)
// 1
```

Note, that newer versions of scala has more concise syntax with [`implicit class` combination](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapper class `MyClassWithName` contains `myClass` and `name` as its members. So, in order to access the `printNumber` function in the class `MyClass`, you need to access the object `myClass` first.

You can write a getter method, use `@BeanProperty` annotation or better yet, use a case class as follows:

```
case class MyClassWithName(myClass: MyClass, val name: String)

val c = myClassWithName(new MyClass, "jonny")
c.myClass.printNumber(5)
```

That would compile.